# Angular: set params in url

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular application > updating an url value.

What I would like to do is to set ONE specific value of my queryparams without altering the rest and without navigating to this url.

So for example, my url is

> https://localhost:4200/some_page?x=0&y=1&z=2

What I now want to do is to set the value for `y` to be something different, but without navigating to it. I want to simply put it in the url field without any side effects.

I already found some way by using the [location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) package

```
  const params = { y : 10 };
  const url = this._router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute, queryParams: params }).toString();

  this._location.go(url);
```

But this approach would remove the values for `x` and `z`. I also cannot get the current params and set a specific value. E.g. this is not possible (I don't exactly know why, the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Params) does not state that it is readonly)

```
this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  (params as any).y = 10;
  const url = this._router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute, queryParams: params }).toString();

  this._location.go(url);
});
```

I must also note that using `Router` is not an option as it still emits navigation events to which subscriptions in the application are doing stuff that they should not do (as it is not a navigation event that I want, ONLY to update some parameters in the url).

```
this._router.navigate([], {
  relativeTo: this._activatedRoute,
  queryParams: { x:1, y: 10, z: 1},
  queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
  skipLocationChange: true // or false, does not matter
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this._router.navigate(['.'], {
  relativeTo: this._activatedRoute,
  queryParams: {
    x: "Xvalue",
    y: "Yvalue",
    z: "Zvalue"
  },
  queryParamsHandling: ''
} );
```

Comment: That still triggers a `NavigationEnd` event